# how to change color help text using crispy tags

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am trying to use cripsy forms for a django website, everything works fine but as you can see my background isn’t white,but blue so the help text doesn’t stand out
How can I change the color of the help text?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color in css, try something more lighter. You can also add a white background to your "help text".

Comment: where exactly in css

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color in css, try something more lighter. You can also add a white background to your "help text". Something like this :

```
help-text {
    color: rgb(240,240,240)
}
```

But it would be so much easier if you could share with me your code ;)